# React Native Firebase: How do you implement Twitter login?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to implement twitter login in a React native app, and I'm using the the react-native-firebase library, but the documentation's Twitter section is completely empty.
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/auth/social-auth

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I also need this. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Looking for help on this as well..

Comment: stilll not answered, I pity the support!!!!

Comment: It is now supported and documented here: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#twitter